# MUI v5 Theme.spacing with predefined object using sx prop

Tags: material-ui

I've set up a custom spacing function for MUI v5 shown below.

```js
    const theme = createTheme({
      spacing: (value) => {
        const spaces = { small: "12px", large: "24px" };

        if (typeof value === 'number') {
          return `${value}px`;
        } else {
          return spaces[value] ? spaces[value] : value
        }
      }
    });
```

Now it works if I do this

```js
    <Box sx={{ ml: (theme) => theme.spacing('small') }} />
```

I would expect this to also work, but it just seems to pass the string right through.

```js
    <Box sx={{ ml: 'small' }}></Box>
```

Is there a way I can get this short form to work? If I'm understanding their documentation right, these two should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can access **spacing** in the following ways:

#### 1: **spacing** as a number

When you define spacing in the theme as a number. The numeric value you've given as the input in sx props will be multiplied by the spacing value in the theme.

```js
        const themeOptions = {
          spacing: 8,
        }
        // Usage
        <Box sx={{ m: -2 }} /> // margin: -16px;
        <Box sx={{ m: 0 }} /> // margin: 0px;
        <Box sx={{ m: 0.5 }} /> // margin: 4px;
        <Box sx={{ m: 2 }} /> // margin: 16px;
```

#### 2: **spacing** as an array:

If spacing is defined as an array in the theme, you can access spacing values by their index.

```js
    // themeOptions
    const theme = {
      spacing: [0, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    }
    //usage
    <Box sx={{ m: -2 }} /> // margin: -3px;
    <Box sx={{ m: 0 }} /> // margin: 0px;
    <Box sx={{ m: 2 }} /> // margin: 3px;
```

**(Nb: Negative input is not to access elements from the end of the array  )**

#### 3: **spacing** as a function:

```js
    // theme options
    const theme = {
      spacing: value => value * 2,
    }
    
    // Usage
    <Box sx={{ m: 0 }} /> // margin: 0px;
    <Box sx={{ m: 2 }} /> // margin: 4px;
```

**Nb: You can't pass a string for the input, string values will be interpreted as plain css**

for eg:

```
    <Box sx={{ m: '2rem' }} /> // margin: 2rem;
    <Box sx={{ mx: 'auto' }} /> // margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
```

refer https://mui.com/system/spacing/